# Getting user locale (country information) in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, locale

I have come into trouble trying to get information about the user's country in my Ionic 3 application. What I need is just the country information from his/her phone locale. So if his phone locale is `en-US`, I am fine just getting the locale as string and splitting it just to retrieve the "US" part.

However, I am unable to get the locale in the format `en-US` . What I tried doing was : 
a) using the angular TranslateService: `translateService.getBrowserLang()` as well as other methods, but I could only get `en` back, not `en-US` .

b) using the cordova globaliation plugin, but I could not get it to work and I quickly found out that it was deprecated since the ECMAScript Internationalization API was released

c) using ECMAScript Internationalization API, but still could not get the user phone's locale in the required format

Can you help? I need something that would work on Android and iOS

Comment: Did you mean you tried this? https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/globalization/ Works fine for me :) getting value `en-US`

Comment: yeah, with this plugin when I call `this.globalization.getPreferredLanguage()` or `this.globalization.getLocaleName()` what I get as an output is a string "und". Tried this with `en-US` locale

Comment: Yeah, tried both, and they worked for me, don't know what to say...

Comment: wait, I just tried this on a real device and got it right. I was testing on an emulator before. Interesting, I thought the emulator locale would work too.. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, emulators are tricky. Always better to test on device, I've learnt ;) But glad to hear it got solved! :)